# Giving titles to subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wanted to give titles to the subplots I was creating.

What I did (I am using Jupyter notebook if this knowledge makes any difference):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,5,11) 
y = x**2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1, ncols =2)
axes[0].plot(x,y)
axes[0].set_xlabel['deneme']
```

The error I received: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

I read the similar question but I could not find an answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

`axes[0].set_xlabel` is a function. To call it, use parentheses, like `axes[0].set_xlabel('deneme')`. Square brackets are for getting a specific element of a collection, usually, like getting the first element of axes by writing `axes[0]`.

To set the title, you might find the `set_title("title")` function useful

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

Comment: Please, post not only code, but also description of what it does and how should it be used